# How to get a 2 into a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a BigInteger I want to divide by two. I tried this:

```
suma=suma.divide(2);
```

or

```
BigInteger a=2;
```

or

```
suma=suma.divide(BigInteger(2));
```

Still the same error saying that 2 is an int.
I am so sorry for such noobish questions.

Comment: Here we go again. 2 is integer. 2.0 will work...

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in [the always-useful JavaDocs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) I suggest you start there.

Comment: I am so ashamed I didn't notice this in the JavaDocs. Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: I want to mention that as of Java 9, you can actually just use `BigInteger.TWO`. My question is, why? `ZERO` and `ONE` were defined in Java 1.2, `TEN` was added in 1.5, and for whatever reason, in version 9, they needed to add in `TWO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following to create a BigInteger with the value 2:

```
BigInteger bigTwo = BigInteger.valueof(2L);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BigInteger Big = new BigInteger("2");
```

its the best way,since if you just assign the numeric 2 or other whole number it will default to integer,as with floats.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
BigInteger bigInt  = new BigInteger("2");
```

To divide:

```
BigInteger bigInt  = new BigInteger("2"); 
BigInteger bigInt2  = new BigInteger("4");
bigInt2 = bigInt2.divide(bigInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot divind a BigInteger value with an integer. You should do it as follows:

```
BigInteger div = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger var = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
var = var.divide(div);
```

It will do your job..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
suma=suma.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
```